Closed form of $\int \frac{\text{d}x}{1+x^3}$
If I had to guess, I think that using partial fraction decomposition would be the "classic way". First remark that
$$ \frac{1}{1+x^3} = \frac{1}{(x+1)(x^2-x+1)}=\frac{ax+b}{x^2-x+1}+\frac{c}{x+1}$$
for some $a,b$ and $c \in \mathbb{R}$. Then
$$\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{(x^2-x+1)} = \frac{(ax+b)(x+1)}{x^2-x+1}+ c &\Longrightarrow c=\frac{1}{3} \\
\frac{1}{x+1} = ax+b  + \frac{1}{3} \frac{x^2-x+1}{x+1} &\Longrightarrow b=1-\frac{1}{3}=\frac{2}{3} \\
\frac{1}{x+1} = ax + \frac{2}{3}  + \frac{1}{3} \frac{x^2-x+1}{x+1} & \Longrightarrow a=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{2}{3}-\frac{1}{6}=-\frac{1}{3}
\end{cases}$$
Therefore
\begin{align} 
\frac{1}{1+x^3} =  \frac{1}{3} \left( \frac{2-x}{x^2-x+1}+\frac{1}{x+1} \right) &= -\frac{1}{6} \left( \frac{2x-1}{x^2-x+1} -\frac{3}{x^2-x+1} -\frac{2}{x+1} \right)
\end{align}
But
$$ \frac{3}{x^2-x+1} = \frac{3}{\left( x-\frac{1}{2} \right) ^2 + \frac{3}{4}} =   \frac{4}{\left[ \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}} \left( x-\frac{1}{2} \right) \right] ^2 + 1}$$
Let $u=\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}} \left( x-\frac{1}{2} \right) \Longrightarrow \text{d} x = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \text{d} u$ which gives us
\begin{align}
\int \frac{3}{x^2-x+1} \text{d}x = 2\sqrt{3} \int \frac{\text{d}u}{1+u^2} = 2\sqrt{3} \arctan \left[ \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}} \left( x-\frac{1}{2} \right) \right]
\end{align}
And finally
\begin{align}
\int \frac{\text{d}x}{1+x^3} = -\frac{\ln|x^2-x+1|}{6}+\frac{\arctan \left[ \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}} \left( x-\frac{1}{2} \right) \right]}{\sqrt{3}} + \frac{\ln |x+1|}{3} + C
\end{align}
for any constant $C \in \mathbb{R}$. Is this correct ? Is there a quicker way of doing it, like a substitution at the beginning maybe ? Or an IBP ?

Hello, welcome to the site. I found several posts about this integral using Approach0.

Looks very interesting. Thank you, I'll check it out !

nice question ...... +1

Substitute $x=\frac{\sqrt3-t}{\sqrt3+t}$ to avoid partial fractions
$$\int \frac{1}{x^3+1}dx=-\frac13 \int \frac{t+\sqrt3}{t^2+1}dt=-\frac16\ln(t^2+1)-\frac1{\sqrt3}\tan^{-1}t
$$

Very instructive. Thank you !

great answer ! +1

Uhh maybe do this
$$\int \frac{x^2}{x^3+1} dx+\int \frac{1-x^2}{1+x^3}dx\\
=\ln|x^3+1|^\frac 13+\int\frac{1-x}{1-x+x^2}dx\\
=\ln|x^3+1|^\frac 13-\ln|x^2-x+1|^\frac12 +\frac 12\int\frac {1}{x^2-x+1}dx$$
The last integral has been solved by you yourself.

Works very well too. Thank you !

:) you're welcome @John
